# "follow a trend of" vs. "follow a trend which leads to be”

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, relative-clauses, reduced-relative-clauses

Is the following grammatically wrong?

> The global car companies follow a trend, which leads to be carbon neutral.

My teacher change it to *The global car companies follow a trend of carbon neutrality*.

I don't know why.

Comment: ...which leads to **being** carbon neutral.

Comment: No; neither. "Follow a trend leading to…" or "follow a trend which leads to…” but those are not the same as the Posted examples, are they?

Comment: Well that is a false statement. Please check the use of the present simple. Your teacher is right. Also, the simple past. Your teacher changed it, not change it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either of them makes *logical* sense, irrespective of grammar.

I'm no expert in the field, but 'carbon neutrality' would mean that a company had achieved 'net zero' for carbon emissions - that doesn't mean they emit no carbon waste, but that their carbon emissions are entirely offset by 'positive' efforts to remove carbon from the atmosphere. **Relatively few companies have achieved this**, but many say they have committed to achieving it by a certain date and have already made steps towards that goal.

The problem with your original statement is that it doesn't state what actually "leads" to carbon neutrality. The 'trend' itself does not achieve that.

The problem with your teacher's amended statement is that it suggests the trend is to *be* carbon neutral, which most companies have not achieved quite yet.

So, if you are trying to say that the 'trend' is for companies to *commit* to it, you could perhaps say:

> The trend among global car companies is to aim to be carbon neutral.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that the teacher's suggestion was not on the veracity of the OP's statement but fixing/improving the grammaticality.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Probably, and that's why I said in my opening line that it made no logical sense, whether or not it is grammatical. I think in cases like this, where we are given two options and asked if one is right and one is wrong, we have a duty to point out if the grammatically correct option is wrong for some other reason.

Comment: Fair enough.... but you also said “which most companies have not achieved quite yet" it seems the main concern is whether the statement is *realistic* based on what we know today. But the solution offered by the teacher is an improvement on the OP's sentence regardless if car companies are following a trend for more eco-friendly vehicles... which they kind of are.